# Summing Row in SQL query for time range

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to group a large amount of data into smaller bundles.

Currently the code for my query is as follows

`SELECT [DateTime]
       ,[KW]
FROM    [POWER]
WHERE   datetime >= '2014-04-14  06:00:00' and datetime < '2014-04-21  06:00:00'
ORDER BY datetime`

which gives me

`DateTime           KW
4/14/2014 6:00:02.0 1947
4/14/2014 6:00:15.0 1946
4/14/2014 6:00:23.0 1947
4/14/2014 6:00:32.0 1011
4/14/2014 6:00:43.0 601
4/14/2014 6:00:52.0 585
4/14/2014 6:01:02.0 582
4/14/2014 6:01:12.0 580
4/14/2014 6:01:21.0 579
4/14/2014 6:01:32.0 579
4/14/2014 6:01:44.0 578
4/14/2014 6:01:53.0 578
4/14/2014 6:02:01.0 577
4/14/2014 6:02:12.0 577
4/14/2014 6:02:22.0 577
4/14/2014 6:02:32.0 576
4/14/2014 6:02:42.0 578
4/14/2014 6:02:52.0 577
4/14/2014 6:03:02.0 577
4/14/2014 6:03:12.0 577
4/14/2014 6:03:22.0 578
.
.
.
.
4/21/2014 5:59:55.0 11`

Now there is a reading every 10 seconds from a substation. Now I want to group this data into hourly readings.

Thus `00:00-01:00 = sum([KW]] for where datetime >= '^date^  00:00:00' and datetime < '^date^  01:00:00'`

I've tried using a convert to change the datetime into date and time field and then only to add all the time fields together with no success.

Can someone please assist me, I'm not sure what is right way of doing this. Thanks

**ADDED**

Ok so the spilt between Datetime is working nicely, but as if I add a SUM([KW]) function SQL gives an error. And if I include any of the group functions it also nags.

Below is what works, I still need to sum the KW per the grouping of hours.

I've tried using `Group By Hour` and `Group by DATEPART(Hour,[DateTime])`

Both didn't work.

`SELECT     DATEPART(Hour,[DateTime]) Hour
    ,DATEPART(Day,[DateTime]) Day
    ,DATEPART(Month,[DateTime]) Month
    ,([KVAReal])
    ,([KVAr])
    ,([KW])
FROM [POWER].[dbo].[IT10t_PAC3200]
WHERE datetime >= '2014-04-14  06:00:00' and datetime < '2014-04-21  06:00:00'
order by datetime`

Comment: when you have a column named [datetime], it's very easy for sql server to confuse that with the datetime type. I would bet that most of your problem centered around that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function [`convert(varchar(13), getdate(), 120)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) displays `2014-06-03 16`.  You can use that to group by the hour:

```
SELECT  convert(varchar(13), [DateTime], 120) as dt
,       SUM(KW) as SumKwPerHour
FROM    POWER
WHERE   [DateTime] >= '2014-04-14 06:00:00' 
        AND [DateTime]< '2014-04-21 06:00:00'
GROUP BY
        convert(varchar(13), [DateTime], 120)
ORDER BY
        dt
```

Comment: Thats quite clever using the 120.  But wouldnt you want to use the `[DateTime]` field instead of `getdate`?

Comment: @paqogomez: Thanks, yeah of course, edited in answer.

Comment: When you do a lot of date grouping these codes will be etched into your brain, but here is a list:  http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/SQLDateTimeFormats.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Ok so here is the solution that worked for me.

`Declare @Begin Varchar(60),
        @End Varchar(60)
Set @Begin = '2014-05-22  06:00:00' 
Set @End = '2014-06-01  06:00:00'`

`SELECT 
    ID='10T'
    ,DATEPART(month,[DateTime]) Month
    ,DATEPART(day,[DateTime]) Day
    ,DATEPART(hour,[DateTime]) as Hour
        ,avg([kw]) hourly_kWh_10T
        ,avg([KVAr]) hourly_kVarh_10T
        ,avg([KVAReal]) hourly_kVAh_10T
        ,(case when(DATEPART(hour,[DateTime]) <=6 and DATEPART(hour,[DateTime]) >18) then 'D' else 'N' end)  shift
  FROM [POWER]
  where DateTime <= @Begin and DateTime > @End
  group by DATEPART(Hour,[DateTime]),DATEPART(Day,[DateTime]),DATEPART(Month,[DateTime])`

This code gave me this result I was looking for. I also include a variable starting point to reduce the input for different dates. + added a if function (Case when) to determine if the power was consumed during Day or Night shift.

`ID Month   Day Hour    hourly_kWh_10T  hourly_kVarh_10T    hourly_kVAh_10T shift
10T 5   22  6   269.278551  80.771587   294.038997  D
10T 5   22  7   241.213296  75.991689   268.085872  D
10T 5   22  8   283.925 93.302777   319.211111  D
10T 5   22  9   11.763888   31.313888   36.372222   D
10T 5   22  10  215.947222  69.702777   243.541666  D
10T 5   22  11  1895.816666 396.805555  1948.061111 D
10T 5   22  12  2385.486033 513.589385  2447.648044 D
10T 5   22  13  440.737569  126.209944  475.049723  D
10T 5   22  14  737.158333  183.05  775.763888  D
10T 5   22  15  41.961111   38.086111   67.277777   D
10T 5   22  16  11.875  30.577777   35.736111   D
10T 5   22  17  11.263888   27.563888   32.497222   D
10T 5   22  18  11.104956   26.381924   31.323615   N
10T 5   22  19  11.648936   28.813829   34.015957   N
10T 5   22  20  229.819944  75.227146   268.432132  N
10T 5   22  21  300.597222  92.661111   340.413888  N
10T 5   22  22  494.575 124.358333  527.183333  N
10T 5   22  23  922.244444  190.472222  954.961111  N
10T 5   23  0   2445.908333 516.008333  2507.613888 N
10T 5   23  1   1399.147222 317.380555  1446.786111 N
10T 5   23  2   258.097222  81.641666   288.308333  N
10T 5   23  3   258.480555  79.694444   285.488888  N
10T 5   23  4   262.108333  82.455555   290.261111  N
10T 5   23  5   270.830555  82.030555   297.011111  N
10T 5   23  6   570.836111  151.930555  606.05  D
10T 5   23  7   10.580555   24.488888   29.233333   D`